# Cannot process "npm install -g create-react-native-app"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

i just started learn React Native. I've already installed Node.js on my mac, and then i try to install React Native by command "npm install -g create-react-native-app" (i followed the installation guide from its official website). But after that, the message below appeared:

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Can anybody tell me the root cause of this problem ? i'm glad if anyone can give me the clue so i can continue my journey to learn this technology (React Native), because i have plan to make a small IOS App Project using this. Thank you ^^.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

run *global* install commands with `sudo`:

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

and enter your password.

Comment: Nooo. Don't sudo everything to fix this. https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: @AnthonyManning-Franklin I never said everything, I said *global*.

Comment: I meant more generally people recommending using sudo as a bandaid fix on SO where it is unnecessary. You do not need to sudo globals. Look at the solutions in the link - there's a reason npm docs do not recommend "just use sudo" and it is a bad habit.

Comment: @AnthonyManning-Franklin They recommend it in their own error description though.